# Is there a way to make a video call possible among the users connected on the same wifi network

Tags: javascript, android, socket.io, webrtc, android-wifi

Is there a way to chat or make a video call possible among the users connected on the same wi-fi network.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

webrtc is a possibility. https://webrtc.org
But you still have to implement a video chat.
Example: https://github.com/fireship-io/webrtc-firebase-demo